# bumblebee ubuntu 15.04

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

I'm trying to get bumblebee to work running Ubuntu 15.04.
I've followed [this](http://rajat-osgyan.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-install-bumblebee-on-ubuntu.html) guide to get to the point I am now, but I'm getting an error that I couldn't even google the way out of it.

This is what I get from `primusrun glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

```
demencia@demencia-laptop:~$ primusrun glxinfo | grep OpenGL
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)
```

But I was told that that error is not really important that I should have a look at my `/var/log/Xorg.8.log`, where I found my dead end.

Here's my [/var/log/Xorg.8.log](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1YHC)
file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the file /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia to include the following screen-section to make bumblebee work:

```
Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Default Screen"
  Device "DiscreteNvidia"
EndSection
```

(To open the file for editing, run `sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` )

After a restart of bumblebee, it works properly.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time for this answer, I hope it helps someone some time, I'm back on Arch and having no problems with hybrid graphics.